# Does my cell phone alarm run off the battery or does it need cell service

Tags: alarm

Will the alarm in my phone go off when programmed if I am in a poor cell reception area?

Comment: Unless you're using some alternative clock app that relies on mobile data or your phone's clock gets wildly out of sync, yes. The alarm is stored locally and uses your phone's clock. Of course, it will not work if the device is off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

The default alarm is built into Android and uses the `alarmManager` to schedule when to sound the alarm.

It will always go off, unless the device is powered off or in silent mode (however some ROM's have separate volume controls for alarms and other volumes).

Comment: That's correct. To my experience, most devices separate alarms from the other volumes (including custom roms as well as stock roms), so unless you explicitly define otherwise, alarms should even fire in "silent mode". An exception might be if the device offers to have "silent hours" (aka "do not disturb"), in which case I'm not sure.